# Absolute maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given this:

$$
f(x,y) = (4x-x^2) \cos \; y \; ;\; 1 \le x \le 3 , \; \frac {-\pi}{4} \le y \le \frac {\pi}{4}
$$

I did the steps below,

$$f_x(x,y)=(4-2x)\cos y$$
$$f_y(x,y)=-(4x-x^2)\sin y$$

I am not sure on how to continue after finding the critical points for the above functions. I referred to this link : [Finding Abs Max and Min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736439/finding-abs-max-and-min). However, i am still confused. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $f_{x}(x,y)=0$ gives either $x=2$ or $\cos y=0$, so $x=2$ since $\cos y\ne 0$ for $y\in[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$.

Setting $f_{y}(x,y)=0$ gives either $x=0$ or $x=4$ or $\sin y=0$.

Therefore the only critical point is $(2,0)$, since $\sin y=0\implies y=0$ for $y\in[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$.

We also need to check points on the boundary of the region at which an extremum can occur, so these include the vertices $(1,-\frac{\pi}{4})$, $(1,\frac{\pi}{4})$, $(3,-\frac{\pi}{4})$, $(3,\frac{\pi}{4})$.

In addition, an extremum may occur at an interior point of an edge:

1) On the left and right edges, with $x=1$ and $x=3$, respectively, $g(y)=3\cos y$ satisfies $g^{\prime}(y)=0$ for $y=0$, so this gives the points $(1,0)$ and $(3,0)$.

2) On the top and bottom edges, with $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=-\frac{\pi}{4}$, respectively, $g(x)=(4x-x^2)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ satisfies $g^{\prime}(x)=0$ for $x=2$, so this gives the points $(2, \frac{\pi}{4})$ and $(2, -\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Now $f(2,0)={4}$, while $f(1,\frac{\pi}{4})=f(1,-\frac{\pi}{4})=f(3,\frac{\pi}{4})=f(3,-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and

$\;\;\;f(1,0)=f(3,0)=3$ and $f(2,\frac{\pi}{4})=f(2,-\frac{\pi}{4})=2\sqrt{2}$.

Now select the largest and smallest of these values.

$------------------------------------$

Another way to do this is to consider the two functions

$g(x)=4x-x^2, 1\le x\le3$ $\text{  and  }$$h(y)=\cos y, -\frac{\pi}{4}\le y\le\frac{\pi}{4}$ separately.

Since both functions are positive-valued and have their maxima at the midpoints and their minima at the endpoints,

the maximum for f occurs at the midpoint of the rectangle and the minimum for f occurs at the 4 vertices of the rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

In order for $f$ to have an absolute maximum or minimum at $(a,b)$, both of the following must be true:

- Either $f_x(a,b) = 0$, or $x = 1$, or $x = 3$.
- Either $f_y(a,b) = 0$, or $y = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, or $y = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Since $\cos y$ is never zero when $y$ is between $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$, the first equation implies $x = 1$, $x = 2$, or $x = 3$.

Since the roots of $4x - x^2$ are $0$ and $4$, outisde of $[1,3]$, the second equation implies $\sin y = 0$, i.e. $y = 0$.

In summary, there are only three possible absolute maxes or absolute mins: $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(3,0)$.
I'll leave it to you to compute the value of $f$ at each point and decide which are the absolute max, which are the absolute min, and which (if any) are neither.